# Spark Standalone and Virtual Environments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

With a spark cluster configured as spark-standalone, we are trying to configure spark-submit jobs to utilize virtual environments managed by pipenv.

The project has this structure:

```
project/
|-- .venv/
   |--bin/python
   |--lib/python3.6/site-packages
|-- src/
   |-- app.py
```

The current attempt involves zipping the virtual environment (`zip -r site.zip .venv`) to include the python executable and all site packages, and ship that along to the executors.

The spark-submit command is currently:

`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./.venv/bin/python \
spark-submit --py-files site.zip src/app.py`

The thinking is that the `--py-files` argument should be unzipping the site.zip into the working directory on the executors, and `.venv` should be reproduced with the `.venv/bin/python` and site-packages available on the python path. This is clearly not the case as we are receiving the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 
0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, [executor-node-uri], executor 0): 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./.venv/bin/python": 
error=2, No such file or directory
```

My question is: is our understanding of `--py-files` correct? I tried browsing the spark source code, but could not follow the flow of the `--py-files` argument in the case that it is a zip file. There are a number of tutorials for YARN mode and shipping conda environments in spark-submit, but not much on spark standalone; Is this even possible?

Addendum::These are the YARN tutorial I was learning from: 
https://henning.kropponline.de/2016/09/17/running-pyspark-with-virtualenv/

http://quasiben.github.io/blog/2016/4/15/conda-spark/

Comment: I don't think the relative path to the venv will work.

Comment: @cricket_007 any specific reason? I tried formulating/constructing the absolute path on the workers, within the python file...i.e. `spark.conf.set('spark.pyspark.python',os.path.join(pyspark.SparkFiles.get('site.zip'),'.venv/bin/python'))` ... which did not work, it seemed to construct the path with the absolute path of the *driver*

Comment: Well, with os path join, you don't need the leading period, or path separators. `SparkFiles.get` should return the absolute path, yes

Answer (score 2):

The --py-files option will not unpack a zip file you provide it. The reason that python can use packages in a zip file is because python supports zips directly. However if the Python binary itself is packaged in such a way then Spark will not be able to locate it.

To achieve this instead you should use the (terribly documented) `--archives` option, which will unzip the archive you provide to a directory you specify:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./.venv/bin/python \
spark-submit \
--archives site.zip#.venv \
src/app.py
```

The rather weird `#` syntax is used to specify an output directory, [documented here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes).

edit: there's also a tutorial on using `venv-pack` to achieve the same thing [here](https://jcrist.github.io/venv-pack/spark.html) though what you're doing should already work.

Comment: the --archives seems to only be supported in yarn how can we do this with spark standalone?

Comment: @KillerSnail I don't think there's a built-in method, since this is a typical task that YARN tries to provide a solution for. You'll need to manually place the necessary files on each node in the cluster.

Comment: yeah I ended up making a custom script to share the files